# java:S2189: "Add an end condition to this loop.". Could you please help me?

Tags: java, while-loop, sonarqube, try-catch

I'm trying to solve this Sonarqube issue regarding this piece of code

```
private void processEvents() {
    long nextSequence = sequence.get() + 1L;

    long groupCounter = 0;
    long msgsInGroup = 0;

    long groupLastNs = 0;

    long l2dataLastNs = 0;
    boolean triggerL2DataRequest = false;

    final int tradeEventChainLengthTarget = sharedPool.getChainLength();
    MatcherTradeEvent tradeEventHead = null;
    MatcherTradeEvent tradeEventTail = null;
    int tradeEventCounter = 0; // counter

    while (true) {
        try {

            // should spin and also check another barrier
            long availableSequence = waitSpinningHelper.tryWaitFor(nextSequence);

            if (nextSequence <= availableSequence) {
                while (nextSequence <= availableSequence) {

                    OrderCommand cmd = ringBuffer.get(nextSequence);
                    nextSequence++;

                    // some commands should trigger R2 stage to avoid unprocessed state in events
                    if (cmd.command == OrderCommandType.RESET
                            || cmd.command == OrderCommandType.PERSIST_STATE_MATCHING
                            || cmd.command == OrderCommandType.BINARY_DATA) {
                        groupCounter++;
                        msgsInGroup = 0;
                    }

                    cmd.eventsGroup = groupCounter;

                    cmd.serviceFlags = 0;
                    if (triggerL2DataRequest) {
                        triggerL2DataRequest = false;
                        cmd.serviceFlags = 1;
                    }

                    // cleaning attached events
                    if (EVENTS_POOLING && cmd.matcherEvent != null) {

                        // update tail
                        if (tradeEventTail == null) {
                            tradeEventHead = cmd.matcherEvent; //?
                        } else {
                            tradeEventTail.nextEvent = cmd.matcherEvent;
                        }

                        tradeEventTail = cmd.matcherEvent;
                        tradeEventCounter++;

                        // find last element in the chain and update tail accourdingly
                        while (tradeEventTail.nextEvent != null) {
                            tradeEventTail = tradeEventTail.nextEvent;
                            tradeEventCounter++;
                        }

                        if (tradeEventCounter >= tradeEventChainLengthTarget) {
                            // chain is big enough -> send to the shared pool
                            tradeEventCounter = 0;
                            sharedPool.putChain(tradeEventHead);
                            tradeEventTail = null;
                            tradeEventHead = null;
                        }

                    }
                    cmd.matcherEvent = null;

                    // TODO collect to shared buffer
                    cmd.marketData = null;

                    if (cmd.command == OrderCommandType.NOP) {
                        // just set next group and pass
                        continue;
                    }

                    msgsInGroup++;

                    // switch group after each N messages
                    // avoid changing groups when PERSIST_STATE_MATCHING is already executing
                    if (msgsInGroup >= msgsInGroupLimit && cmd.command != OrderCommandType.PERSIST_STATE_RISK) {
                        groupCounter++;
                        msgsInGroup = 0;
                    }

                }
                sequence.set(availableSequence);
                groupLastNs = System.nanoTime() + GROUP_MAX_DURATION_NS;

            } else {
                final long t = System.nanoTime();
                if (msgsInGroup > 0 && t > groupLastNs) {
                    // switch group after T microseconds elapsed, if group is non empty
                    groupCounter++;
                    msgsInGroup = 0;
                }

                if (t > l2dataLastNs) {
                    l2dataLastNs = t + L2_PUBLISH_INTERVAL_NS; // trigger L2 data every 10ms
                    triggerL2DataRequest = true;
                }
            }

        } catch (final AlertException ex) {
            if (running.get() != RUNNING) {
                break;
            }
        } catch (final Throwable ex) {
            sequence.set(nextSequence);
            nextSequence++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is about that while(true) loop with a try catch inside. I've tried to put while(true) into the try block but this created huge compilation error.
This code has not been written by me, but it is a project given me by my teacher for the exam.

Comment: sonarqube is trying to tell you it's usually not good to hardcode 'while(true)'. how are you breaking out of that loop?

Comment: now i've tried to write as condition of the while "nextSequence !=0". Could this make sense?

Comment: I don't know, since I don't know the logic about your loop

Comment: Neither do i, because as i said this is not a code written by me

Comment: then first learn what it does/should do before trying to change anything

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a variable so that instead of

```
while (true) {
    ...
}
```

You can control it from within the loop

```
boolean running = true;
...
while (running) {
    ...
    if (condition) {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively create a method to validate whatever criteria are necessary if the loop is to keep iterating:

```
while (isValid(input)) {
    ...
}
```

And define the method

```
boolean isValid( ... method args here ... ) {
    ...
}
```

If for example the loop should keep going for as long as `nextSequence` is not 0, this can all be simplified to

```
while (nextSequence != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Note that you can't use a compile time constant in this case. If it were set to false you would get an error due to unreachable code.

Comment: Now i've only tried to use variable "nextSequence" and put it into the while like this "while(nextSequence) != 0". Does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you so much for these suggestions. I'm trying this way